# Biztalk MQSeries MQSC Set Header Version Property

Tags: ibm-mq, biztalk

We are using Biztalk 2016 and MQSC adapter for send message to IBM MQ but when we want to set below properties in Orchestration or Pipeline Component we could not able to set correctly. This issue raised when Version less than "2" in IBM documentation. How can we able to set MQMD Version Property correclty?

[image]

Comment: Are you using context properties ? The Biztalk documentation would suggest that these fields are available (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/mqseries-context-properties).

Comment: Yes, I'm using context properties. For example I've set MQMD_GroupID property in orchestration but property value not write to MQ. I could not find where to set Version for message.

Comment: How do you know that the property value is not written in the message? What are you using to view the message after it is written?